# Do different opacities of hover / click / active states need considering from an accessibility perspective?

Tags: accessibility, color-scheme, wcag, color-blindness

I found this sidebar [on Dribbble](https://dribbble.com/shots/20530181-Sidebar-navigation-Untitled-UI):

[image]

And I'm wondering if it's fully accessible? It looks like when a menu item is active, it's given a semi-transparent background. And when you hover over another menu item, it's also given a semi-transparent background, for as long as you're hovering over it.

The question I'm having is - is this type of design WCAG compliant? Because if you take a screenshot and use the eyedropper tool to get the hexes, the background of an active menu item is #547BEE with the text being close to white at #F5FFFE, and this actually fails an accessibility check on [WebAim](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/)

[image]

But does that matter? Maybe the background is not actually #547BEE, but really #ffffff at 4% opacity? For example, these rectangles have different hexes, but they look similar:

[image]

Does color contrast still matter to WCAG when the background has a reduced opacity?

Comment: Usually color contrast is computed using the element's RGB value but when an opacity is applied, you have to use the color that's rendered and not the RGB value.  3.78 fails unless the font is [14pt+bold or 18pt+normal](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#dfn-large-scale)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes!** WCAG contrast ratio requirements still must be met on hover, active, and focus states. The only state that doesn't require contrast minimums is the disabled state.

It's worth noting, as [mentioned in this article](https://accessibleweb.com/question-answer/what-are-the-contrast-requirements-for-an-elements-focus-mouseover-select-states/), that contrast minimums don't have to be met across states. For example, hover doesn't have to provide a minimum amount of contrast with the default idle state. But text on a background is still text on a background and subject to contrast requirements.

Comment: I think the "yes" answer is to the OP's last question, *"Does color contrast still matter to WCAG when the background has a reduced opacity?"*.  The "yes" answer does **not** apply to *"I'm wondering if it's fully accessible?"* nor to *"is this type of design WCAG compliant?"* because those answers are "no".

Comment: Correct - there were a few questions here, I answered the last one. :)

Comment: You may want to make that clear in your answer. You said “yes” and then qualified it by saying contrast applied to hover and other states, which actually wasn’t one of the OP’s questions. They were asking if contrast applied to opacity, not hover. The opacity happened to be applied when you hovered. You have good info, just update your answer to make it clear which question you are answering and that you are also answering a question that was not asked, namely, is contrast required between states, which you correctly said “no“.

Answer (score 1):

We all know dribbble isn't compliant with standards and accessibility issues. Just change the background color to a darker one.